# PHP: Compute the duration [seconds/minutes]

Tags: php, seconds

I have a database and also have a fields for fldDuration. Where everytime I input some commercial it also have a field for duration. The fldDuration is the actual time of the commercial.

Example:

fldCommercialName, fldDuration and fldTotalDuration
I insert a value..

Commercial Name: NIKE [inputted]

Duration: 15 seconds [inputted]

Total Duration: 11:45 mins [will be appeared based on computation of fldDuration and fldTotalDuration and after I click the button]

So the total of per commercial is 12 mins. So for this example I will deduct the 15 sec to 20 mins. Then the total now is 11:45 mins [this is the remaining duration for the commercial].

Problem: How can I do that like what I said above this message.

*I don't have any code's yet for this because I don't know how I will do the computations.

Thanks.

Comment: Most time, even full dates are tracked in seconds. The math from that is easy, `/60` to get minutes...etc. This is usually just an integer and the math gets easy.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... you could try defining a trigger to fire `BEFORE INSERT`, that runs:

```
SET new.`fldTotalDuration` = 20*60 - (SELECT SUM(`fldDuration`) FROM `tablename`) - new.`fldDuration`
```

This should calcuate the value correctly.

That said, this kind of thing is best computed on the PHP side.

Comment: @Kolink...what is the "new" after the set...? and the "new before the flduration?

Comment: In a trigger, `new` refers to the new row that's being handled.

Comment: @Kolink...what if I didn't used the "new"? because I'm planning to do to my database fields are..."CommercialName", "fldDuration", fldTotalDuration"..then in my form I will display the commercialname and fldtotalduration.

Comment: Erm... then it won't update the rows, it will try to set global variables with those names.

Comment: @Kolink...I see...then after that.. how can I make it like a minutes with ":" ?? 12:00..like that? I will view the total duration in the form..